# Cron job can't use 'For' loop?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I have the following code:

```
EntityManager mgr = null;
try {
    mgr = getEntityManager();
    ZooperTheme2 theme = null;
    theme = mgr.find(Theme2.class, "1");
    theme.setPopularity(7);
    mgr.persist(theme);
    for (int c = 1; c < 204; c++) {
        theme = mgr.find(Theme2.class, "" + c);
        theme.calculatePopularity();
        mgr.persist(theme);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
} finally {
    mgr.close();
}
```

The part before the 'For' loop:

```
theme = mgr.find(Theme2.class, "1");
theme.setPopularity(7);
mgr.persist(theme);
```

Works just fine **by itself**.  But when I add the 'For' loop to iterate across all of the themes, none of the themes are updating (including theme "1" using .setPopularity(7).  The log files show the following error:

```
   Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Illegal argument
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:298)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:197)
    at com.companionfree.zooperthemeviewer.CronController.doGet(CronController.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:39)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:94)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$6.getFutureWithOptionalTimeout(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:373)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$6.aggregate(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:345)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$6.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:316)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$6.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:305)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$TxnAwareFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:58)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.get(WrappedDatastoreService.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.getEntityFromDatastore(EntityUtils.java:667)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.updateObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:415)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3841)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternalWithOrdering(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3888)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3811)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flush(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3751)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4141)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.transactionPreCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:428)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:398)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:287)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1090)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:193)
    ... 35 more
```

CronController.java:43 is the line:
    mgr.close()

It appears my code is failing when I add the For loop but I can't tell why...

Comment: You have "PersistenceException". Problem is not for loop! It looks that your code is running in transaction and I guess that in this transaction also other entities are updated.

Comment: I understand that @MatejC however the problem still remains and occurs as soon as that For loop is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview)

"The app uses the factory instance to create one EntityManager instance for each request that accesses the datastore."

I was clued in that EntityManager can only call persist once and errors out if you try to use it on more than one object.  My new code is:

EntityManager mgr = null;
        Theme2 theme = null;

```
    for (int c = 1;c<204;c++) {

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();           
            theme = mgr.find(Theme2.class, "" + c);
            theme.calculatePopularity();

            mgr.persist(theme);


        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

    }
```

And it works perfectly :)